# Spring Boot | parsing Url with query params in properties file with URIComponentBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, url

I have a URL in my `application-local.properties` file which looks like

```
basePath: http://host.com/
endpoint: /endpoint?q={value1}
```

I am mapping it to variables in a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. I am using `URLComponentBuilder` to build the full URL like this:

```
 UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(basePath).path(properties.endpoint).build(123)
```

The URL I am getting is this: `http://host.com/endpoint%3Fq=123` i.e. the `?` gets encoded.

The question is that I don't want to remove query params from the properties file and add them only in the code where I am building the URL. I want to keep the full URI `endpoint` in the properties file and still be able to generate the correct (without `?` being encoded) full URL through `URIComponentBuilder`